# python how to make a list into columns in pandas df

Tags: pandas

I have a list as follows:

```
[[100,200,300],[10,20,30,40]]
```

I want to transform each element into a column of a pandas `df`

The end result looks like:

```
Col1   Col2    Col3    Col4
100    200     300
10     20      30       40
```

How can I achieve this?
There is a max size of 4 items per list but could be lower.

Comment: im not sure if I miss something, but just simple `df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists)` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
lst = [[100,200,300],[10,20,30,40]]
pd.DataFrame(lst).add_prefix("Col")
```

Comment: What if (and I think thats also what the OP wants to know) the 4-column-df is the base. Our input list has a max size of 4 or less. Now if none of the list of lists have a length of 4 (1st list 3, 2nd list 3 elements) then I get an error when passing the data to the df `ValueError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns` .any idea how to fill that df except just fill it by looping ?

Comment: Use `add_prefix`

Comment: unfortunately not what i meant. DataFrame has to have always 4 columns. if you pass the list of lists into that df (saying one list has 3 elements, one has 2) then the last column of the df has 2 Nan but still there are 4 column there.

Comment: `.reindex(columns=range(4))`